# How to find the maxvalue of a sequence(especially hana sequence)

Tags: sequence, hana

I can see the queries to get currval and nextval of sequence online. But is there a query to get maxvalue of the sequence as well, as I need to change the maxvalue of the sequence. To be precise:

```
if(currentMaxValue = 999) {
   
ALTER SEQUENCE "seqname" maxvalue 9999;

}
```

How exactly can I fetch the `currentMaxValue` of the sequence defined.

To get the nextval, the query would be:

```
SELECT "seqname".nextval FROM "tablename"
```

In the same way, would this work:

```
SELECT "seqname".maxvalue FROM "tablename"
```

Asking this because, I cannot test this in my local development.

Comment: Why not just set this value to almost infinite and do not bother about it? Is there any drawbacks of high maxvalue? It is not available as sequence pseudocolumn (like `currval` or `nextval`) because there's no practical usage of that value, the purpose of sequence is just to provide sequential numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the current defined max value (and all other metadata) for a sequence from system view [SEQUENCES](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.05/en-US/20cf0e79751910149462bf9e7d571ab8.html). There is not equivalent to NEXTVAL or CURRVAL for the max value.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to set a large limit to the sequence.
You have the freedom to set it between `-9999999999999999999999999999 and 9999999999999999999999999999`

You can also get the max value for the sequence from the system views `Sequences` or `M_SEQUENCES`.

```
Select SEQUENCE_NAME, CURRENT_VALUE,end_value from M_SEQUENCES where upper(SEQUENCE_NAME) =upper('<seqName>');
```